# How to show elements on FXML file loaded in JavaFX application?

Tags: java, css, javafx, fxml

I need to understand how to show elements inserted in FXML file loaded by Main javaFX application, my JavaFX application main is:

```
// imports omitted
public class Main extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage window) throws IOException {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Standard.fxml"));
    Scene mainGraphic = new Scene(root,500,500);

    window.setTitle("Prova con FXML");
    window.setMinHeight(500);
    window.setMinWidth(500);
    window.setScene(mainGraphic);
    window.show();
    }
}
```

This file works and load properly the FXML file `Standard.fxml`, the problem is that it doesn't show the top rectangle, this is the FXML file:

```xml
// imports omitted    
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.myname.mypackage.Controller">
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@Standard.css"/>
    </stylesheets>

    <Rectangle id="ParteSuperiore"/>
</AnchorPane>
```

I obvioulsy have created the CSS file and stylized the element with the property I want, this is the CSS:

```css
#AnchorPane {
    -fx-background-color: rgb(224, 246, 255);
}

#ParteSuperiore {
    -fx-fill: rgb(255, 145, 28);
    -fx-arc-height: 100px;
    -fx-arc-width: 100px;
}
```

What is wrong in this file? I can only see the AnchorPane's background color! I tried to put the `Rectangle` inside `<children>` element, however i continue to see only the AnchorPane's background color and I don't see the Rectangle! Should I use a Region instead of a Rectangle? If yes, how can I give width and height to it? In [JavaFX CSS reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region) it doesn't give me the instruction to set width and height, like `-fx-arc-height` of the rectangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be confusing the `arcHeight`/`arcWidth` properties and the `height`/`width` properties of [`Rectangle`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/shape/Rectangle.html). According to the documentation, the `arcHeight` property:

> Defines the vertical diameter of the arc at the four corners of the rectangle. The rectangle will have rounded corners if and only if both of the arc width and arc height properties are greater than `0.0`.

And the `height` property:

> Defines the height of the rectangle.

*The `arcWidth` and `width` properties have similar documentation.*

Both the `width` and `height` properties have a default value of `0.0`. Since you don't define a width or height for your `Rectangle` there is nothing to render. Looking at the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#rectangle)'s documentation for `Rectangle`, along with `Shape` and `Node`, there is no way to set the width or height of a `Rectangle` from CSS<sup>1</sup>. You'll need to do it in code or in the FXML file. For example:

```xml
// imports omitted    
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.myname.mypackage.Controller">
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@Standard.css"/>
    </stylesheets>

    <Rectangle id="ParteSuperiore" width="100" height="100"/>

</AnchorPane>
```

And you'll probably want to remove, or at least change, the `-fx-arc-width` and `-fx-arc-height` values in the CSS file.

---

<sup>1. Looking at the [implementation](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/blob/develop/modules/javafx.graphics/src/main/java/javafx/scene/shape/Rectangle.java) confirms this. Neither `width` nor `height` is an instance of `StyleableProperty`, unlike `arcWidth` and `arcHeight`.</sup>

Comment: By giving height and width from FXML it takes size in px, is it possible to give sizes in percentage in these fields (trying it cause me an error)?

Comment: Not directly, no. Setting the width and height via code or FXML uses pixels. You could try to use [expression bindings](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#expression_binding) to your advantage though (or just bindings if in code).